# I can't get my rock, paper, scissors program to read the correct results

Tags: java

Whenever I run it, it seems that the loop to continue playing works, but the game outcome is not outputting correctly whenever the conputerChoose executes the randomGenerator.  Please help.  I'm new to java, and we are only suppose to use 3 methods - instructions, playGame and computerChoose.  We are also suppose to use a user controlled loop to continue working.  I can't seem to get this right and I still have to add a loop to count the number of time sthe game has been played, the number of times won and the number of times the computer won.

```
import java.util.*;

public class PRS {

    public static Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void instructions() {

        System.out.println("\nThis is the popular game of paper, rock, scissors.  Enter your"
                + "\nchoice by typing the word \"paper\", the word \"rock\" or the word"
                + "\n\"scissors\".  The computer will also make a choice from the three"
                + "\noptions.  After you have entered your choice, the winner of the"
                + "\ngame will be determined according to the following rules:"
                + "\n\nPaper wraps rock (paper wins)"
                + "\nRock breaks scissors (rock wins)"
                + "\nScissors cuts paper (scissors wins)"
                + "\n\nIf both you and the computer enter the same choice, then the game "
                + "\nis tied.\n");

    }

    public static int playGame(){

        int outcome = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
        kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        String player = kbd.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        String computerChoice = computerChoose();
        System.out.println("\nYou entered: " + player);
        System.out.println("Computer Chose: " + computerChoose());

        if(player.equals(computerChoose())){

            outcome = 3;


        } 

        else if (player.equals("paper") && computerChoice.equals("rock")){

            outcome = 1;

        }
        else if (computerChoice.equals("paper") && player.equals("rock")){

            outcome = 2;
        }
        else if (player.equals("rock") && computerChoice.equals("scissors")){


            outcome = 1;


        }
        else if (computerChoice.equals("rock") && player.equals("scissors")){
            outcome = 2;

        }

        else if (player.equals("scissors") && computerChoice.equals("paper") ){

            outcome = 1;
        }

        else if (computerChoice.equals("scissors") && player.equals("paper")){

            outcome = 2;
        }

        else if (player.equals("rock") && computerChoice.equals("paper") ){

            outcome = 2;
        }

        else if (computerChoice.equals("rock") && player.equals("paper")){

            outcome = 1;
        }
        return outcome;

    }


    public static String computerChoose(){

        /*return "scissors";*/
        Random generator = new Random();
        String [] answer = new String [3];
        answer [0]= "paper";
        answer [1] = "rock";
        answer [2] = "scissors";
        return answer[generator.nextInt(3)];

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("THE GAME OF PAPER, ROCK, SCISSORS:");

        System.out.print("\nDo you need instructions (Y or N)? ");

        String userPlay = kbd.nextLine();

        if (userPlay.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
            instructions();
        }




        String answer;
        do{

            int result = playGame();

            System.out.println(result);
            switch (result){
            case 1: 
                System.out.println("YOU WIN!");
                break;
            case 2: 
                System.out.println("Comp WINs!");
                break;
            case 3: 
                System.out.println("IT'S A TIE!");
                break;
            default:
            }

            System.out.print("\nPlay again ( Y or N)? ");
            answer = kbd.nextLine();

        }while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));


    }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is only call `computerChoose()` once. Every time you are calling this method it is generating a new random number and hence a different answer. You should only call it once inside `playGame()` and assign it to a local variable.

E.g.

```
String computerChoice = computerChoose();
```

Then replace all of your other calls to `computerChoose()` with this variable name. This way you will display the one value and compare only the one value in your logic.

As for tracking other information such as the number of games, and the number of wins/losses, think about declaring a few more class variables (or local variables in the main method) which you can then assign, increment and read. You can do all this from within your do-while loop in the main method. No need for any additional loops.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  But ii'm still getting an odd response when I hit yes when asked if i want to continue.  it keeps printing out the same result as the last one no matter what the outcome is.

Comment: See the answer from @ArmaAK below, he picked up what I missed in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Adam's answer, changing the do-while loop at the end to the following will resolve a few different issues.

```
String answer;
int winCount=0, lossCount=0, tieCount=0;
do{
    int result = playGame();

    switch (result){
    case 1: 
        System.out.println("YOU WIN!");
        winCount++;
        break;
    case 2: 
        System.out.println("Comp WINs!");
        lossCount++;
        break;
    case 3: 
        System.out.println("IT'S A TIE!");
        tieCount++;
        break;
    default:
    }

    System.out.print("\nPlay again ( Y or N)? ");
     answer = kbd.nextLine();

}while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
System.out.printf("Wins: %d, Losses: %d, Total plays: %d%n", winCount, lossCount, winCount+lossCount+tieCount);
```

You need to update `result` inside the while loop or else only the first game's results will be accurate.

Comment: Thanks.  IT worked to an extent.  But for some reason it is now printing a number before the result line.  Also, the second go around it is printing 0 when I put paper in .

Comment: this is my output so far:

Comment: Sorry, that was me debugging. Take out that print statement underneath the call to `playGame()`

Comment: //You entered: rock
Computer Chose: scissors
1
YOU WIN!

Play again ( Y or N)? y
Enter your choice: paper

You entered: paper
Computer Chose: rock
0

Play again ( Y or N)?

Comment: Its like after the 3rd time i hit yes, it starts spitting out wrong outcome again and after that it stops printing out outcome and just a number.

Comment: You missed a couple `computerChoose()` calls (around line 25). Change those to your new variable `computerChoice` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I did miss that.  I forgot to add that to a comment.  Thank you so much.  It worked.  Not so worried about the count loop at the end, but would the loop to count the number of times be okay if I nest them?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know what you mean. Could you give an example of what you want to do?

Comment: The assignment required a counter for the number of times the game has been played, the number of wins, and the number of losses after the user decides to hit NO if they wanna play again.  What would these three variables need to be assigned to in the main method to get my count correct?  thank you for your help btw.

Comment: Oh I see now, I edited my post to include the counting. I didn't test the code, but I'm pretty sure it should work out. And you're welcome for the help :D

Comment: Thank you.  I see where you are going with it, but eclipse popped up red warning errors.  I'm wondering if it iw because the variables are outside of theloop.

Comment: Ok there, I made one more edit. That should do it. :D

Comment: Thank you.  I saw that shortly after I replaced it.  I remembered another similar project had the same issue with not initializing the variables.  Thank you VERY much for your suggestions and for a great explanation.